# Capture to a location based on on location in org-tree

Tags: org-capture

`org-capture` has a highly customizable set of capture locations using  [org-capture-templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html). I've used this for doing things like capture to the current task I am working on using `org-clock` or to capture to the parent of a node etc.

What I'd quite like to do at the moment is to be able to specify within an org-heading where I should capture to using a property? Is there a good way of doing this?

Example:

- Things that I want to look at after reading the paper
- Notes on paper that I'm reading
- - When I do an "org-capture" here, I want things to get captures to "things that I want..."

Comment: Example please? What you are asking for is not clear to me.

Comment: I added an example